Code to finish. Webots robot
I have made code where robot should finish the labhyrint. The code is for student and I want to know can somebody finish the code before I will put this to students task.
Code:
from controller import Robot
Time step of the simulation
TIME_STEP = 64
Initialize the robot
robot = Robot()
Get the wheel motors
left_motor = robot.getDevice('motor.left')
right_motor = robot.getDevice('motor.right')
left_motor.setPosition(float('inf'))
right_motor.setPosition(float('inf'))
left_motor.setVelocity(0.0)
right_motor.setVelocity(0.0)
Get the distance sensors
ds_left = robot.getDevice("distance sensor left")
ds_left.enable(TIME_STEP)
ds_front = robot.getDevice("distance sensor front")
ds_front.enable(TIME_STEP)
ds_right = robot.getDevice("distance sensor right")
ds_right.enable(TIME_STEP)
counter = 0
Main loop
while robot.step(TIME_STEP) != -1:
t = counter*TIME_STEP*1e-3
counter += 1

# Read the distance sensor values
ds_values = [ds_left.getValue(), ds_front.getValue(), ds_right.getValue()]

print("t = {0:.3f} s, d_L = {1:.0f}, d_F = {2:.0f}, d_R = {3:.0f}".format(t,ds_values[0],ds_values[1], ds_values[2]))

print(" ")        
       
# Left-hand rule logic
# Build the logic here
if t < 1.0:
   left_speed =  1.0
   right_speed = 1.0
elif t < 3.5:
   left_speed =  4.0
   right_speed = 1.0
else:
   left_speed =  3.0
   right_speed = 3.0

# Set wheel speeds

left_motor.setVelocity(left_speed)
right_motor.setVelocity(right_speed)

